# Inheriting from a class defined in an imported module in Python

Tags: python

I have two Python classes in two separate modules. The modules reference each other, so I must use the `import XXX` syntax rather than `from XXX import YYY`. I can't figure out how to access a class defiend in one module in the other, importing module though:

```
### testa.py

import testb

class TestA():
  ...

### testb.py

import testa

class TestB(testa.TestA):  # doesn't work
  ...
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why are you importing `testb` in `testa.py`?

Comment: Circular importing. Why?

Comment: If you remove `import testb` from `testa.py` it will work fine. The problem you're having seems to be related to the circular imports rather than subclassing from a different module.

Comment: `TestA` objects contain other `TestA` objects, including `TestB` objects. In some `TestA` methods `TestB` objects need to be instantiated. Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: I was about to repeat what univerio has written, so refer to that. I don't know what your code actually looks like but you may want to re-consider the way your modules are laid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by putting `import testb` after the definition of `TestA`. However, you might need to rethink your module structure since circular imports are difficult to deal with.